# ASP.NET Core submit values based on claims

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an HTML form that is sent to a controller action (via POST) based on MVC.

The form contains different inputs. There are extra inputs if the user has certain claims.
For example, if the User is administrator, he/she sees an additional text area for comments.

```
public class MySubmit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IsActive { get; set; }

    // only an administrator should be able to set this field
    // for all other users, this should be empty
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}

public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult MyActionResult(MySubmit submit)
    {

    }
}
```

What is the best and safest way to process the result on the action?
Theoretically it is possible that the a tries to submit values although he/she does not actually see the corresponding form controls, because he/she does not have the claim.

I would like to set default values used for field values instead, if the user does NOT have these claims - no matter what values he sends for these fields.

Is there anything built in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bryan Lewis gave the right hint: Fluent Validation.

Fluent Validation has the ability to use the HTTP context via Dependency Injection to receive the user and perform a claim comparison:

```
public class YourModelValidator: AbstractValidator<YourModel>
{
    public YourModelValidator(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.YourProprty).Custom( (html, context) =>
        {
            var user = httpContext.User;

            if (!user.HasClaim(c => c.Type.Equals(claim))
            {
                context.AddFailure("Claim is missing.");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can validate the value, but you should not set the value.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best solution I think!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anything built in?

No. There's no built-in way to do that.

#### Design

You might want to achieve that with a custom model binder. But I believe that's not a good way. Because you'll have to process all kinds of input formatters at the same time. Think about somewhere your action expects a  `[FromForm]MySubmit mySubmit` while another action expects a `[FromBody] Submit mySubmit`. The first action requires a payload of form, while the second action might expect a JSON. Even you take care of the two above scenarios, what about you want to enable XML payloads in future? In short, you can hardly write a general Model Binder for this.

Validation might help. But validation usually makes you repeat yourself if you have several models( Think about you have ten domain models, each one has several properties that requires some claims)

IMO, a better way is to use `ActionFilter`. Since `ActionFilter` takes place after the model binding, it would be possible to erase the field when the field requires a role.

To do that, create a custom attribute to mark which property requires some role:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple=false)]
internal class RequireRolesForBindingAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string[] Roles {get;}
    public RequireRolesForBindingAttribute(params string[] roles)
    {
        this.Roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Now when some roles are required, simply annotate the target property like below:

```
public class MySubmit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IsActive { get; set; }

    // only an root/admin can bind this field for all other users, this should be empty
    [RequireRolesForBindingAttribute("root","admin")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public Sub Sub{get;set;}    // test it with a complex child 
}

public class Sub{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [RequireRolesForBindingAttribute("root","admin")]
    public string Note {get;set;}
}
```

The above data annotation represents that the two properties should be erased if the user has no rights:

- `Comment` property of `MySubmit`
- `Note` property of `Sub`

Finally, don't forget to enable an custom action filter. For example, add it on action method:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(RequireRolesForBindingFilter))]
public IActionResult Test(MySubmit mySubmit)
{
    return Ok(mySubmit);
}
```

#### An Implementation of `RequireRolesForBindingFilter`

I create an implementation of `RequireRolesForBindingFilter` for your reference:

```cs
public class RequireRolesForBindingFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authSvc;

    public RequireRolesForBindingFilter(IAuthorizationService authSvc)
    {
        this._authSvc = authSvc;
    }
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // skip early when User ==null, 
        //    if you don't want to allow anonymous access, use `[Authorize]`
        if(context.HttpContext.User !=null) {  
            await this._checkUserRights(context.ActionArguments, context.HttpContext.User);
        }
        await next();
    }
    private async Task _checkUserRights(IDictionary<string, object> args, ClaimsPrincipal user){
        // handle each argument
        foreach(var kvp in args){
            if(kvp.Value==null) { return; }
            var valueType = kvp.Value.GetType();
            if(await _shouldSetNullForType(valueType, user)) {
                args[kvp.Key] = valueType.IsValueType? Activator.CreateInstance(valueType) : null;
            }else{
                // handle each property of this argument
                foreach(var pi in valueType.GetProperties())
                {
                    var pv = pi.GetValue(kvp.Value);
                    await _checkPropertiesRecursive( instanceValue: kvp.Value, propInfo: pi, user: user);
                }
            }
        }

        async Task<bool> _shouldSetNullForType(Type type, ClaimsPrincipal user)
        {
            // the `RequireRolesForBindingAttribute`
            var attr= type 
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequireRolesForBindingAttribute), false)
                .OfType<RequireRolesForBindingAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
            return await _shouldSetNullForAttribute(attr,user);
        }
        async Task<bool> _shouldSetNullForPropInfo(PropertyInfo pi, ClaimsPrincipal user)
        {
            // the `RequireRolesForBindingAttribute`
            var attr= pi
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequireRolesForBindingAttribute), false)
                .OfType<RequireRolesForBindingAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
            return await _shouldSetNullForAttribute(attr,user);
        }
        async Task<bool> _shouldSetNullForAttribute(RequireRolesForBindingAttribute attr, ClaimsPrincipal user)
        {
            if(attr!=null) {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireRole(attr.Roles).Build();
                // does the user have the rights?
                var authResult = await this._authSvc.AuthorizeAsync(user, null, policy);
                if(!authResult.Succeeded){ 
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        // check one property (propInfo) for instance `instanceValue`
        async Task _checkPropertiesRecursive(object instanceValue, PropertyInfo propInfo,  ClaimsPrincipal user){
            if(instanceValue == null) return;
            Type propType = propInfo.PropertyType;
            object propValue = propInfo.GetValue(instanceValue);
            if(await _shouldSetNullForPropInfo(propInfo, user))
            {
                propInfo.SetValue(instanceValue, propType.IsValueType? Activator.CreateInstance(propType) : null);
            }
            else if( !shouldSkipCheckChildren(propType) && propValue!=null ){ 
                // process every sub property for this propType
                foreach(var spi in propType.GetProperties()) 
                {
                    await _checkPropertiesRecursive(instanceValue: propValue , spi, user );
                }
            }

            bool shouldSkipCheckChildren(Type type) => (type == typeof(string) || type == typeof(DateTime));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Demo:

When some user, who has no rights to submit the comment and note filed, sends a payload as below:

```
POST https://localhost:5001/home/test
cookie: <my-cookie>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

name=a&isActive=true&comment=abc&sub.Name=s1&sub.note=magic
```

The response will be:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
  "name": "a",
  "isActive": "true",
  "comment": null,
  "sub": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "s1",
    "note": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are really two actions that you want to perform -- validation and conditional editing of the incoming model.  For complex validation, you should consider using something like FluentValidation (https://fluentvalidation.net/), which is quite flexible, integrates with MVC's ModelState and will allow you to check all sorts of things based on conditions.  It's not clear from your post if you referring to "claims" in the general sense or specifically to ASP.Net Identity Claims -- either way, you can pull identity information into the FluentValidation Validator and create conditional checks based on identity information.  The validators (FV or otherwise) don't really handle resetting/editing the model.  For your example, you can simply alter the model directly after the validation is complete.

```
// if Validation is successful

if (isAdmin) {   // however you are checking their role
   submit.Comment = null;  // or whatever the default value should be
}

// Do something with the incoming model / dave to DB etc
```

Comment: We have claims of the ASP.NET Core Identity Model. My idea was to "sanitize" the model before the values will be binded to the "submit" object; via Attribute or custom model binder. I will take a look on FluentValidation